# Как выбрать при помощи регулярного выражения все строки, кроме той, у которой содержится известная подстрока?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть несколько строк:

```
 - http://localhost/hello/trt/trtrt 
 - http://localhost/api/test
 - http://localhost/webapi/test/value
```

Так вот необходимо выбрать все строки кроме последней, у которой отличительная особенность - это слово ***webapi***, до и после которого имеется текст

Comment: В общем-то regexp не нужен: достаточно простого поиска через strstr подстроки "webapi".

Comment: Или см. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word по-английски.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов наоборот исключить

Comment: @gromanev и что же вам мешает исключить строки, в которых "webapi" будет найдена?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов то что это я применяю не в коде а в готовом решении

Comment: А на выходе то регулряки что должно быть и "готовое решение" каким диалектом регулярных выражений пользуется. А то ведь их много и в разных по разному делается одно и то же ... pcre `(?!.*webapi)` но возможны варианты по тому что возвращать ...

Comment: @Mike возвращать все строки нужно, где в тексте нету webapi

Comment: А что, приведенный мной пример не работает что ли ? тогда точно уточните какой диалект используется в вашем продукте. Ибо он на pcre-совместимых выражениях должен работать, ну может `.*` в начале или конце добавить для захвата всей строки

Comment: ТС: укажите язык, где Вы применяете регулярные выражения. Да и вообще, ознакомьтесь с разделом "Как задать вопрос про регулярные выражения" по ссылке http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/info